# iframe and validate.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have iframe inside my page for save data in database.I use `validate.js` to validate a field inside a iframe.If I validate field outside a iframe means in same page its work.If i do same thing in iframe its doesn't work.I want to know `validate.js` doesn't work inside a iframe?
I try:

```
var v = $("#form1").validate({
                    ignore: ':hidden',
                    rules: {
                        txtTitle: { required: true },
                        txtPost: { required: true },
                        txtSummary: { required: true }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        txtTitle: "Please enter a Post Title",
                        txtPost: "Please enter a Post description",
                        txtSummary: "Please enter a Post Summary"
                    }
                });
```

And in button click I use like this.

```
 $("#btnPost").live("click", function() {
                    if (v.form()) {
                     alert("Success");
                    }
                    else {
                    alert("fail");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

`note:txtTitle,txtPost,txtSummary,btnPost all are iframe controls.`Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely you're using iFrames on different domains. jQuery won't traverse the iFrame as it would be a violation of the browsers cross-site policies. You won't be able to touch the inner-DOM if this is the case.

A solution would be to bind is to DOM events, but without knowing your form code I won't be able to give you an exact solution to your problem. It'll probably be like this:

```
$("#form1").contents().onclick = function() { // validate here };
```